# Angular parâmetros não obrigatório na rota

Tags: angularjs

Tenho uma tela onde preciso passar um parâmetro de acordo com a sua chamada, ou seja, tem chamadas que não é necessário a passagem do parâmetro e tem chamadas que são consultas diretas que é necessário a passagem do parâmetro.

Minha dúvida é como faço caso não queira passar o parâmetro (parâmetro é do tipo inteiro, onde estou passando 0 (zero)) para que não fique com a url e o valor zerado. exemplo:

Sem parâmetro:

```
 http://localhost:9080/sc/#/logistica/requisicoes/0
```

Com parâmetro:

```
http://localhost:9080/sc/#/logistica/requisicoes/2000936
```

Minha rota:

```
.state('app.logistica.requisicoes', {
                    url: '/requisicoes/:id',
                    templateUrl: 'views/logistica-requisicoes.html',
```

Gostaria que a minha URL quando não fosse necessário o parâmetro ficasse sem o zero.

```
http://localhost:9080/sc/#/logistica/requisicoes
```

Comment: Deu certo @user11890, a resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O padrão para um parâmetro opcional é adicionar no final o sinal de `?`, exemplo:

```
.state('app.logistica.requisicoes', {
                    url: '/requisicoes/:id?',
                    templateUrl: 'views/logistica-requisicoes.html',
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [AngularJS: Trabalhando com Parâmetros Opcionais](https://medium.com/@nncl/angularjs-trabalhando-com-par%C3%A2metros-opcionais-cab8c96f2183)
- [AngularJS: Definindo rotas com com ngRoute e UI-Router](https://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/angular-definindo-rotas/)
- [AngularJS: Definindo parâmetros opcionais com UI Router](https://rafaell-lycan.com/2016/angular-definindo-parametros-opcionais-ui-router/)